# AngularJS sharing data form AJAX $http request

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have the following controllers:

```
angular.module('app').controller('ParentCtrl', function(Service) {

   var list = []
   var init = function () {
      Service.query().success(function() {
          list = Service.getList();  
      });
   }
});

angular.module('app').controller('ChildCtrl', function(Service) {

   var list = []
   var init = function () {
      list = Service.getList();
   }
});

angular.module('app').factory('Service', function($http) {

     list = []
     return {
         query : function() {
             $http.get('/path/to/my/api').success(function(data){
                list = data
             })
         },
         getList: function() {
             return list;
         }
     }
  });
```

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl as parent">
    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl as child">

    </div>
</div>
```

So basically when I receive the AJAX request I want both the controllers to get updated with the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to return the promise from `$http.get`:

```
angular.module('app').factory('Service', function($http) {
   var promise;
   return {
     getList: function() {
         if (promise) {
             return promise;
         }

         promise = $http.get('/path/to/my/api');
         return promise;
     }
   }
});

angular.module('app').controller('ParentCtrl', function(Service) {    
   var list = [];
   var init = function () {
      Service.getList().then(function(response) {
          list = response.data;  
      });
   }
});

angular.module('app').controller('ChildCtrl', function(Service) {
   var list = [];
   var init = function () {
      Service.getList().then(function(response) {
          list = response.data;  
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: hmm bu this would make a duplicate server call though. I believe purpose of OP was not to perform duplicate server calls hence OP has 2 different methods.

Comment: Yeah, similar idea. Probably a bit too similar, slightly simpler

Comment: :) i just elaborated with more options.. It is pretty simple as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can broadcast custom message to rootScope and Your controllers will get this message and handle it.

```
angular.module('app').controller('ParentCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, Service) {

   $scope.list = [];

   $scope.$on('Service:list', function(event, data){
       $scope.list = data;
   });
});

angular.module('app').controller('ChildCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, Service) {

   $scope.list = [];

   $scope.$on('Service:list', function(event, data){
       $scope.list = data;
   });

   Service.query(); // run once, get in both controllers
});

angular.module('app').factory('Service', function($rootScope, $http) {
     var list;

     return {
         query : function() {
             $http.get('/path/to/my/api').success(function(data){
                list = data;
                $rootScope.$broadcast('Service:list', list);
             })
         },
         getList: function() {
             return list;
         }
     }
});
```

Comment: Though this would work for this specific example, this can cause a major design flaw in terms of who should make the first call etc.. IMHORefactoring or making enhancement could lead to difficulties (In my experience) especially when publishing event from services also not to forget you need to inject `$rootScope` in a service, which sometimes is a weird thing.

Comment: This answer is for current question. But it's interesting for me which kind of difficulties it could make, You need to publish data through event - so use rootScope, no need - so don't define it.

Comment: example:- if you have another sibling controller using the same data now who should make the first `query` call so that duplicate calls are not made? Or if call is made from different components (or controllers just to simplify) who decides who should make `query` call.. It would fallback in such a way that other components has a hidden dependency on the one who is supposed to make the call. that is what i meant.

Comment: all of them +  use promises :)
as I said: this example for this question

Comment: I think there is lot of talks about right choises. Everybody writes how he(she) whishes. :)

Comment: Yup. i guess nobody is against it.. and generally comment box is for discussion as well. Generally people like it (at least i do like comments on my answer whether somebody shows a mistake/constructive criticism/alternate options or whatever helps me and future readers).. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could handle it in many ways. One simple way is to cache the promise and return it.

Example:-

```
angular.module('app').factory('Service', function($http, $q) {
     var listPromise;
     return {
         getList: function() {
             //If promise is already present then 
             return listPromise || (listPromise = $http.get('/path/to/my/api').then(function(response){
                return response.data;
             })
             //Use the below 2 blocks (catch and finally) only if you need.
             //Invalidate in case of error
             .catch(function(error){ 
                  listPromise = null;
                  return $q.reject(error);
             })
            //Use finally to clean up promise only if you only need to avoid simultaneous request to the server and do not want to cache the data for ever.
            .finally(function(){ 
                listPromise = null;
             }));
         }
     }
  });
```

and in controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('ParentCtrl', function(Service) {
   var list = [];
   var init = function () {
      Service.getList().then(function(data) {
          list = data;  
      });
   }
});

angular.module('app').controller('ChildCtrl', function(Service) {

   var list = [];
   var init = function () {
      Service.getList().then(function(data) {
          list = data;  
      });
   }
});
```

Caching a promise will make sure that it really does not matter who makes the first call and you always make the same service call to get the data and service will manage data caching via promise and prevent any duplicate calls.

Another practice is to implement a one-way data flow using [flux pattern](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html). Where you create stores that maintains data and it will make ajax call via a dispatcher and emits event to the subscribers of change event. There is an angular library (**[flux-angular](https://github.com/christianalfoni/flux-angular)**) that can be used as well to implement this pattern. This will really help synchronize data between multiple components regardless of whether they are parent/child or siblings and regardless of who makes the first call etc..